# Can I use if else statement with onclick?

Tags: javascript

I want to Sort array of objects by string property value.
So if I click a button, the values will be sorted. 
But only the first if statement works. if I change the else if statement into the first if statement, it works but no matter what I do only the first if statement works. 
What should I change to make all three buttons work?

```js
var members = [{
  name: "jar",
  join: "2017-2",
  sex: "f",
  age: "29"
}, {
  name: "hrk",
  join: "2017-8",
  sex: "f",
  age: "21"
}, {
  name: "jjk",
  join: "2014-6",
  sex: "m",
  age: "27"
}, {
  name: "jsh",
  join: "2016-5",
  sex: "m",
  age: "37"
}, {
  name: "kks",
  join: "2014-4",
  sex: "f",
  age: "42"
}];
var list = "";


function func() {
  for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
    var val = document.getElementById('form').ans.value;

    if (members[i].join >= val || members[i].name == val || members[i].sex == val || members[i].age == val) {

      for (var key in members[i]) {
        if (key === "name" || key === "join" || key === "sex") {

          if (document.getElementById("namebtn").onclick) {
            var namesort = function(a, b) {
              if (a.name > b.name) {
                return 1;
              } else if (a.name < b.name) {
                return -1;
              }
              return 0;
            }
            members.sort(namesort);
          } else if (document.getElementById("joinbtn").onclick) {
            var joinsort = function(a, b) {
              if (a.join > b.join) {
                return 1;
              } else if (a.join < b.join) {
                return -1;
              }
              return 0;
            }
            members.sort(joinsort);
          } else if (document.getElementById("joinbtn").onclick) {
            var agesort = function(a, b) {
              if (a.age > b.age) {
                return 1;
              } else if (a.age < b.age) {
                return -1;
              }
              return 0;
            }
            members.sort(agesort);
          }
          br = " ";
        } else {
          br = "<br>";
        }
        list += members[i][key] + br;

      }
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = title;
  document.getElementById("who").innerHTML = list;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<p id="title"></p>
<p id="who"></p>
<form action="#" id="form">
  <input type="text" name="ans" placeholder="year">
  <input type="submit" value="search" id="sub">
</form>
<br>
<input type="submit" onclick="func()" id="namebtn">
<input type="submit" onclick="func()" id="joinbtn">
<input type="submit" onclick="func()" id="agebtn">
```

Comment: Can you indent your code properly? It is hard to read right now.

Comment: What do you expect that `if( document.getElementById("namebtn").onclick )` would check?

Comment: `if (document.getElementById("joinbtn").onclick) {...} else if (document.getElementById("joinbtn").onclick) {...}` Code inside this `else if` will never be reached.

Comment: Where is `title` defined?

Comment: I erased title in the snippet because it is written in another language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (document.getElementById('namebtn').onclick)` will always be true since the attribute is truthy.

Are you trying to check which button was clicked? If that's the case, your func should probably have an `id` or `event` parameter (`function func(btnId or e) { ... }`) and then pass `this.id` to `func`:

`<input type="submit" onclick="func(this.id or event)" id="namebtn">`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking `document.getElementById("elementid").onclick`, you can find the target of the current click event. Look this example.

```js
var members = [{name: "jar",join: "2017-2",sex: "f",age: "29"}, 
               {name: "hrk",join: "2017-8",sex: "f",age: "21"},
               {name: "jjk",join: "2014-6",sex: "m",age: "27"},
               {name: "jsh",join: "2016-5",sex: "m",age: "37"},
               {name: "kks",join: "2014-4",sex: "f",age: "42"}];
var list = "";


function func(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
        var val = document.getElementById('form').ans.value;
        if (members[i].join >= val || members[i].name == val || members[i].sex == val || members[i].age == val) {

            for (var key in members[i]) {
                if (key === "name" || key === "join" || key === "sex") {

                    if (e.currentTarget.id == "namebtn") {
                        var namesort = function (a, b) {
                            if (a.name > b.name) {
                                return 1;
                            } else if (a.name < b.name) {
                                return -1;
                            }
                            return 0;
                        }
                        members.sort(namesort);
                    } else if (e.currentTarget.id == "joinbtn") {
                        var joinsort = function (a, b) {
                            if ((new Date(a.join)).getTime() > (new Date(b.join)).getTime()) {
                                return 1;
                            } else if ((new Date(a.join)).getTime() < (new Date(b.join)).getTime()) {
                                return -1;
                            }
                            return 0;
                        }
                        members.sort(joinsort);
                    } else if (e.currentTarget.id == "agebtn") {
                        var agesort = function (a, b) {
                            if (parseInt(a.age) > parseInt(b.age)) {
                                return 1;
                            } else if (parseInt(a.age) < parseInt(b.age)) {
                                return -1;
                            }
                            return 0;
                        }
                        members.sort(agesort);
                    }
                    br = " ";
                } else {
                    br = "<br>";
                }
                list += members[i][key] + br;

            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = title;
    document.getElementById("who").innerHTML = list;
    return false;
}
```

```html
<p id="title"></p>
<p id="who"></p>
<form action="#" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="ans" placeholder="year">
    <input type="submit" value="search" id="sub">
</form>
<br>
<input type="submit" onclick="func(event)" value="name" id="namebtn">
<input type="submit" onclick="func(event)" value="join" id="joinbtn">
<input type="submit" onclick="func(event)" value="age" id="agebtn">
```

Also you can use some better comparison methods for date and age. I have updated that in my code.

Comment: Is it just me or 2nd and 3rd conditions are same?

Comment: @Rajesh not just you, 3rd condition will never be reached, I pointed that out in a comment to OP.

Comment: It should be `agebtn`. Seems like a typo

Comment: Yes, it is. I have corrected that typo. Also, you can use some better comparison methods for date and age. I have updated that in my code.

Answer (score 0):

> But only the first if statement works. if I change the else if
>   statement into the first if statement

Because `onclick` value is not **falsey** and `else` is unlikely to be executed.

> What should I change to make all three buttons work?

You can simplify by passing the **property** by which sorting should happen, here is a **demo** of the same

```js
var members = [
    { name: "jar", join: "2017-2", sex: "f", age: "29" },
    { name: "hrk", join: "2017-8", sex: "f", age: "21" },
    { name: "jjk", join: "2014-6", sex: "m", age: "27" },
    { name: "jsh", join: "2016-5", sex: "m", age: "37" },
    { name: "kks", join: "2014-4", sex: "f", age: "42" }
];

var list = "";

function func( prop ) 
{
  sortObjByProp(members, prop);
  list = members.map( function( memberObj ){  
     return Object.keys( memberObj ).map( function( key ){
        return "<span class='cell'>" + memberObj[ key ] + "</span>";
     }).join( "  " );
  }).join( "<br>" );
  
  document.getElementById("who").innerHTML = list;
  return false;
}

function sortObjByProp(obj, prop) 
{
  obj.sort(function(a, b) {
     return a[prop].localeCompare(b[prop]); //will work for numerics like age if the number of digits are same for all ages.
  });
}
```

```css
.cell
{
   display :inline-block;
   width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<p id="who"></p>
<form action="#" id="form">
  <input type="text" name="ans" placeholder="year">
  <input type="submit" value="search" id="sub">
</form>
<br>
<input type="submit" onclick="func('name')" id="namebtn" value="sort by name">
<input type="submit" onclick="func('join')" id="joinbtn" value="sort by join">
<input type="submit" onclick="func('age')" id="agebtn" value="sort by age">
```

Comment: @guest271314 It does for me. I can see that names starting by `h` are followed by names starting from `j` and finally followed by name starting with `k`

Comment: Since OP's data is all string, you can just use `a[prop].localeCompare(b[prop])`

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the logic by defining the sort functions outside of `func` function, attach event handlers to each element using `.addEventListener()` or `.onclick`. Call `func()` within an event handler attached to the element. Use `var` to define variables, specifically `br` and `list`

```js
var members = [{
  name: "jar",
  join: "2017-2",
  sex: "f",
  age: "29"
}, {
  name: "hrk",
  join: "2017-8",
  sex: "f",
  age: "21"
}, {
  name: "jjk",
  join: "2014-6",
  sex: "m",
  age: "27"
}, {
  name: "jsh",
  join: "2016-5",
  sex: "m",
  age: "37"
}, {
  name: "kks",
  join: "2014-4",
  sex: "f",
  age: "42"
}];

var namesort = function(a, b) {
  if (a.name > b.name) {
    return 1;
  } else if (a.name < b.name) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}

var joinsort = function(a, b) {
  if (a.join > b.join) {
    return 1;
  } else if (a.join < b.join) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}

var agesort = function(a, b) {
  if (a.age > b.age) {
    return 1;
  } else if (a.age < b.age) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}

document.getElementById("joinbtn").onclick = function() {
  members.sort(joinsort);
  func();
};

document.getElementById("agebtn").onclick = function() {
  members.sort(agesort);
  func();
}

document.getElementById("namebtn").onclick = function() {
  members.sort(namesort);
  func();
};

function func() {
  var br = "";
  var list = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
    var val = document.getElementById('form').ans.value;

    if (members[i].join >= val || members[i].name == val || members[i].sex == val || members[i].age == val) {

      for (var key in members[i]) {
        if (key === "name" || key === "join" || key === "sex") {
          br = " ";
        } else {
          br = "<br>";
        }
        list += members[i][key] + br;

      }
    }
  }
  // document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = title;
  document.getElementById("who").innerHTML = list;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<p id="title"></p>
<p id="who"></p>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="ans" placeholder="year">
  <input type="button" value="search" id="sub">
</form>
<br>
<input type="button" id="namebtn" value="name">
<input type="button" id="joinbtn" value="join">
<input type="button" id="agebtn" value="age">
```

Answer (score 0):

As rightly suggested by @[nitheesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6099327/nitheesh), you should use `event.currentTarget.id` instead of `onClick`.

Few pointers,

**Note:** These pointers are mere suggestions and are highly dependent on individual's perspective. If you think they help you in anyway, use them. If not, just ignore them.

- If you define `document.getElementById(...).onClick = function(){...}`, this will replace your original handler. It might even break the logic
- Having a handler on markup can make your code more fragile as they are rendered along with HTML, so anyone looking at the source of your page can see the names. You should use `addEventListener` for this.
- You should try to reuse your code more. Instead of having multiple sort functions, have a generic function that returns a sort function. This way you can handle more cases with less code.
- Try to use better naming conventions. `func` is a bad function name. A function name should denote its purpose.

```js
var members = [{ name: "jar", join: "2017-2", sex: "f", age: "29" }, { name: "hrk", join: "2017-8", sex: "f", age: "21" }, { name: "jjk", join: "2014-6", sex: "m", age: "27" }, { name: "jsh", join: "2016-5", sex: "m", age: "37" }, { name: "kks", join: "2014-4", sex: "f", age: "42" }];

function getMySortFn(key) {
  return function(a, b) {
    return a[key].localeCompare(b[key]);
  }
}

function func(e) {
  var list = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
    var val = document.getElementById('form').ans.value;

    if (members[i].join >= val || members[i].name == val || members[i].sex == val || members[i].age == val) {
    var shouldSort = ['namebtn', 'joinbtn', 'agebtn'].indexOf(e.currentTarget.id) > -1;
      for (var key in members[i]) {
        if (key === "name" || key === "join" || key === "sex") {
          if(shouldSort) {
            members.sort(getMySortFn(e.currentTarget.id.replace('btn', '')));
          }
          br = " ";
        } else {
          br = "<br>";
        }
        list += members[i][key] + br;
      }
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = title.innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("who").innerHTML = list;
  return false;
}

var btns = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="submit"]');
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener('click', func);
}
```

```html
<p id="title"></p>
<p id="who"></p>
<form action="#" id="form">
  <input type="text" name="ans" placeholder="year">
  <input type="submit" value="search" id="sub">
</form>
<br>
<input type="submit" id="namebtn" value='name'>
<input type="submit" id="joinbtn" value='join'>
<input type="submit" id="agebtn" value='age'>
```

Comment: _"Try to use better naming conventions. `func` is a bad function name. A function name should denote its purpose."_ How are  "naming conventions" and "bad function name" related to the Question? While you were busy editing this users' Answer you could have removed opinion irrelevant to the actual Question from your own Answer.

Comment: Hey, lets take it easy. I tried to give few suggestions that in my POV were apt. If anything is wrong with them, please highlight it.

Comment: The last bullet point at your Answer is entirely opinion wholly unrelated to the Question. You must be aware of that fact.

Comment: @guest271314 Giving helpful advice on question code is encouraged. See [this meta topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357926/1288408).

Comment: @ModusTollens Have no concern for what is "encouraged" at meta. Meta has a culture onto itself. Why do you consider the "advice" "helpful"? `func` being used as a function name is not an issue at this Question nor any other Question. There is no review guild for function names being used in code, perhaps at codereview, not at SO. There is pseudo code abound in both questions and answers at SO.

Comment: @guest271314 I added my comment mainly to point out that fact, for users passing by.

Comment: @ModusTollens What fact are you trying to point out? A fact about opinion?

Comment: @guest271314 That adding general coding advice to answers is ok.

Comment: @ModusTollens The "advice" at present Answer is opinion and entirely unrelated to the Question. Whether the opinion is "ok" or not is also irrelevant. A function can be named anything within the valid names for a function in JavaScript. "bad function name" is subjective and lacking in definitive meaning. What is "good function name" and whom decides the distinction between "good" and "bad"? meta? chat?

Comment: @guest271314 Chill, it was just a general remark from me (and not even an important one). If you find the answer unhelpful, downvote it.

Comment: @ModusTollens Have not cast a "downvote" for an Answer. If the opinion serves a purpose for some, they can follow that opinion. From perspective here, the naming of functions is wholly unrelated to the Question. The function `func` could have been named a symbol `_`, and the code at Question would still have the same issues. And there would probably be an opinion as to not naming functions using symbols, while the same viewer offering and opinion might answer `$` jQuery and `_` underscore or lodash questions using the same symbols and be silent as to the libraries' use of the symbols.